# Sitecore instance not logging anymore after import with SIM-Tool

Tags: logging, sitecore, sitecore-instance-manager

I have a Sitecore instance that doesn't write log files anymore. It was exported with the SIM-Tool and then imported with a different name. The original instance logs just fine.

Why doesn't the imported instance write logs? Is there a setting I'm missing?

Comment: Check the log directory in the config and check the permissions on that folder. does not seem to me very complicated?

Comment: Also check the datafolder directory it might be in a different location now. Do a showconfig.aspx and see where the datafolder setting is at.

Comment: In the sitecore.config the dataFolder is defined like this: <sc.variable name="dataFolder" value="/data" />. But the showconfig.aspx still shows the wrong path (the path of the original instance). Why is that?

Comment: use the /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx then you see also the patches. inside the include folder

Comment: as you export using SIM there should be patch of datafolder configuration inside \App_Config\Include\zzz\DataFolder.config

Comment: Wow, so there are TWO DataFolder patches? One in /include (with the correct path) and one in include/zzz (with the wrong old path). I didn't see the one in the zzz folder. After changing the path in that, the logs are back. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, then I'll add it as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you export using SIM there should be patch for datafolder configuration inside \App_Config\Include\zzz\DataFolder.config

Please, reconfigure it.

Comment: And as said, make sure is not Locked/Read-Only and you have proper rights.